# Stack Implementation in C [Array] Issue- "this" must be a modifiable lvalue

Tags: c, arrays, generics, stack

I'm working on a generic-implementation of a stack in C, and I seem to be getting the aforementioned error when trying to push or pop. 
Here is my code below:

Header file:

```
#ifndef STACK_H_
#define STACK_H_

#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct Stack Stack;

struct Stack {
    void* element;
    int top;
    int capacity;
    int size; 
};


Stack* new_Stack(int max_size);

bool Stack_push(Stack* this, void* element);

void* Stack_pop(Stack* this);

int Stack_size(Stack* this);

bool Stack_isEmpty(Stack* this);

#endif
```

C File:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include "Stack.h"

Stack *new_Stack(int max_size) {
    Stack* stack = malloc(sizeof(Stack)); 
    stack->capacity = max_size; 
    stack->top = -1; 
    stack->size = 0;
    stack->element = calloc(sizeof(void*)*max_size); 
    return stack;
}

bool Stack_push(Stack* this, void* element) {

    if (this->top >= this->capacity-1){
        return false;
    }

    this->element[this->top++] = element;
    return true;
}


void* Stack_pop(Stack* this) {

    if(Stack_isEmpty(this)){
        return NULL;
    }
    else {
        return this->element[this->top--];
    }
}

int Stack_size(Stack* this) {
    return this->size; 
}


bool Stack_isEmpty(Stack* this) {
    if(this->top = -1){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the push() & pop() functions, the lines "this->element[this->top++] = element;" and "return this->element[this->top--]", are causing the error "*this* must be a modifiable lvalue".

Comment: shouldn't the 'element' member in struct Stack be the array of void pointers?

Comment: `void *element` --> `void **element`

Comment: Also that since your `top` is `-1`, you will get an immediate error trying to push because you are assigning value to `element[-1]`

Comment: I should definitely have checked that before posting! Thanks!

Comment: How would I fix that? Add "top++" before the placement of the element?

Comment: maybe either `top=0` at creation or `element[++top]`...